# How to do a post to flask from a button

Tags: javascript, python, flask

How do I make a post request from java to flask?
Why can I get the data sent to the server?

```html
 <button name="send" id = "sendbutton">Send</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById("sendbutton").addEventListener('click', () => {
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/truthMask", true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
        //alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
        console.log("sent");
    };
    r.send(input="test");
});
```

```py
@app.route('/truthMask', methods=['POST'])
def set_truthMask():
    print("Got the data")
    foo = request.args.get("input")
    print("Print the data: {}".format(foo))
    return "sent"
```

Comment: In the python you need `request.form` not `request.args` ... said where does "input" come from? You need to send that either in the Javsacript or from a form input

Comment: how do I send it from the javascript?  XMLHttpRequest is inside this function. My end goal is to be able to send a canvas image but I can't even figure out how to send a string. I prints "got the data" but print the data is none. Any help would be super super useful and appreciated.

Comment: @Cfreak sorry forgot to put your name in the reply

Comment: No worries. I went to sleep anyway. I misunderstood the image part :). Looks like you've got a good answer below!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS Code

```
document.getElementById("sendbutton").addEventListener('click', () => {
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/truthMask", true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
        //alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
        console.log("sent");
    };
    // Send data in below way from JS
    r.send(JSON.stringify({"input": "test"}));
});
```

Python Flask API

```
import json

@app.route('/truthMask', methods=['POST'])
def set_truthMask():
    print("Got the data")
    foo = json.loads(request.data.decode())["input"]
    print("Print the data: {}".format(foo))
    return "sent"
```

Don't forget to import `json`

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd also suggest you send the content-type header with `application/json` in the request. When you do that you can avoid the extra call to load `json` and use `request.get_json()` from flask instead.

Comment: friend can you see the other post I made? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67100956/flask-send-a-png-image-to-the-browser-and-display-in-javascript-canvas