# Flask send a png image to the browser and display in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Still learning Flask and web dev in general. I have no clue how to send a png image from flask to the browser. I just want to be do some image processing then send it to the browser when I'm done so I can view it in a javascript canvas. The images are not static but get generated on the fly. So I just save them in flat files and somehow need to send it the browser so I can view it in a JavaScript canvas. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have the image converted I just want to be able to open it in a JavaScript canvas.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Flask png -> Browser ???

```py
#Flask stuff 
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request,jsonify, json, after_this_request, send_file
import base64
import io


#just have to figure out how to SEND images back to browser!!!
@app.route('/getImage', methods=['GET'])
def get_Image():
    #...
    #process image with cv2 then save so I can send it the the browser 
    #...
    image = get_encoded_img("img\\truthMask.png")
    return jsonify({'image_url': image})

def get_encoded_img(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path, mode='r')
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
    my_encoded_img = base64.encodebytes(img_byte_arr.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
    return my_encoded_img
```

```js
const canvasMask = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
/*The user mask 2d context*/
const ctxcanvasMask = canvasFinalConsensusMask.getContext('2d');


document.getElementById("getMask").addEventListener('click', () => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Setup our listener to process compeleted requests
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Only run if the request is complete
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;

        // Process our return data
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            // What do when the request is successful
            console.log("I got the image");
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            var img = new Image(),
                f = data.image_url,
                url = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
                src = url.createObjectURL(f);
            img.src = src;
            img.onload = function () {
                ctxFinalConsensusMask.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                url.revokeObjectURL(src);
            }
        }
    };
    // Create and send a GET request
    // The first argument is the post type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
    // The second argument is the endpoint URL
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/getImage');
    xhr.send();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: 1;">
                    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
<button name="getMask" id="getMask"> Show Mask </button>
```

Comment: what do you get ? in browser? Did you use `print()` in Flask to see what you send? Did you sue `alert()` or `console.log()` in JavaScript to see what you get ? Did you try to open `http://127.0.0.1:5000/getImage` directly in web browser to see what you get? Don't you get any error message when you run Flask? Maybe it shows you something interesting. Or maybe you get some error message in JavaScript console.

Comment: if you image in `base64` then you could assing it directly with prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64` - like `src='data:image/jpeg;base64,  ... image in base64 ...'`

Comment: you could create minimal working code which we could run. You could add `app = ...` ,`app.run()`, `for PIL inport Image` - it would be easier to help you. And you have to explain what is `canvasFinalConsensusMask` because you don't create it in code. You create only `canvasMask`.

Comment: I finally run your code and JavaScript console shows problem with names `canvasFinalConsensusMask` and `ctxFinalConsensusMask` which you didn't create in code. I expect you used wrong names and they should be `canvasMask` and `ctxcanvasMask`  (which you created)

Comment: https://buraksenol.medium.com/pass-images-to-html-without-saving-them-as-files-using-python-flask-b055f29908a Try This

Comment: btw: if youc reated image with `cv2` or `numpy` then you can convert it to `pillow` without saving in file - `Image.fromarray(cv_image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code to create minimal working code - and it sends image to browser.

All problem was with names of variables in JavaScript.

You create objects `canvasMask` and `ctxcanvasMask` but you try to get data from `canvasFinalConsensusMask` and `ctxFinalConsensusMask` which don't exist.

```
const canvasMask = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctxcanvasMask = canvasMask.getContext('2d');
```

I had also problem with `url.createObjectURL(f)` so I assign image directly to varialble `img.src` using `base64` image with prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64,`

```
img.src='data:image/jpeg;base64,...image in base64...'
```

like this:

```
        let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        console.log(data.image_url);

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.image_url;
        
        img.onload = function () {
            ctxcanvasMask.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
```

---

Minimal working code

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from PIL import Image
import base64
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getImage') # as default it uses `methods=['GET']`
def get_Image():

    #...
    #process image with cv2 then save so I can send it the the browser 
    #...
    
    #image = get_encoded_img("img\\truthMask.png")
    image = get_encoded_img("img/lenna.png")  # I use Linux path with `/` instead of `\\`
    
    return jsonify({'image_url': image})

def get_encoded_img(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path, mode='r')
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
    my_encoded_img = base64.encodebytes(img_byte_arr.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
    return my_encoded_img

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: 1;">
                    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
<button name="getMask" id="getMask"> Show Mask </button>

<script>    
const canvasMask = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctxcanvasMask = canvasMask.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById("getMask").addEventListener('click', () => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Setup our listener to process compeleted requests
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Only run if the request is complete
        if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;

        // Process our return data
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            // What do when the request is successful
            console.log("I got the image");
            
            let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            console.log(data.image_url);

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.image_url;
            
            img.onload = function () {
                ctxcanvasMask.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    };
    // Create and send a GET request
    // The first argument is the post type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
    // The second argument is the endpoint URL
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/getImage');
    xhr.send();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Result:

[image]

---

**BTW:** I used image `lenna.png` from Wikipedia [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `cv2` (or `numpy`) to create image then you don't have to save it but you can directly convert `Image.fromarray(cv_image)`

```
@app.route('/getImage') # as default it uses `methods=['GET']`
def get_Image():
    img = cv2.imread("img/lenna.png")
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
    
    img = Image.fromarray(img)
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
    image = base64.encodebytes(img_byte_arr.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
    
    return jsonify({'image_url': image})
```

You can even convert `cv2` image to `base64` without `pillow` and `BytesIO`

```
@app.route('/getImage') # as default it uses `methods=['GET']`
def get_Image():
    img = cv2.imread("img/lenna.png")
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
    
    ret, buf = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
    
    image = base64.b64encode(buf).decode('ascii')
    
    return jsonify({'image_url': image})
```

Instead of old `XMLHttpRequest()` you can use modern `fetch()`

```
<script>    
const canvasMask = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctxcanvasMask = canvasMask.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById("getMask").addEventListener('click', () => {

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getImage')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.image_url;
        img.onload = () => ctxcanvasMask.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    })
    .catch(err => alert("PROBLEM\\n\\n" + err));
    
});
</script>
```

---

The final code:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import cv2
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getImage')
def get_image():
    img = cv2.imread("img/lenna.png")
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
    
    ret, buf = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
    
    image = base64.b64encode(buf).decode('ascii')
    
    return jsonify({'image_url': image})

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: 1;">
                    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
<button name="getMask" id="getMask"> Show Mask </button>

<script>    
const canvasMask = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctxcanvasMask = canvasMask.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById("getMask").addEventListener('click', () => {

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getImage')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.image_url;
        img.onload = () => ctxcanvasMask.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    })
    .catch(err => alert("PROBLEM\\n\\n" + err));
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want only convert `filename` to `base64` them you don't need `Image` and `BytesIO`. You need only `open(..., 'rb').read()`

```py
@app.route('/getImage')
def get_image():
    image = get_encoded_img("img/lenna.png")

    return jsonify({'image_url': image})

def get_encoded_img(image_path):
    data = open(image_path, 'rb').read()
    return base64.encodebytes(data).decode('ascii')
```